# Android application - three questions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-actionbar

I am writing an Android application at the moment, no knowledge of java what so ever, except what I have learnt in the last 5 hours. I've managed to implement a two screens and a nice looking layout.

I have three questions:

1. How do I set the Action Bar on Honeycomb to be transparent like in the Google Maps application? I want to be able to partially see the background graphic through it.
2. What code to use to empty five edit texts and a textview on button click? I've read something about a viewgroup, but I have no idea how to implement that...
3. I have a linearlayout with a tablelayout centred horizontally and vertically inside it, and eleven table rows in that. How do I set a partially transparent black as a sort of fill colour for the tablelayout without ruining the background of the linearlayout? Every time I try to set a fill colour it blacks out the entire background image of the layout surrounding it as well.

Plain english would be preferable because I am so new to this.
Thanks heaps for any replys, have a great day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your 1st question: You can implement a theme on the HoneyComb action bar. Check this [link](http://p-xr.com/customizing-the-action-bar-in-honeycomb/) for more info. The color would be something like this: #29000000.

The first hex 2-digit(**#29**) represents alpha channels of color and set opacity. If value is “00” that means 100% transparent. if value is set it will be **opaque**, it can be any value in 00 to FF.

More links on styling the Action Bar:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Example project is to be found here:

- http://p-xr.com/customizing-the-action-bar-in-honeycomb/

Comment: Have you done this yourself? I have attempted to implement it four or five times now and I still have no luck. If someone could find a full example workspace for me that would be great.

Comment: No, haven't tried doing this yet.( HoneyComb emulator is sooo slow :-) ). Ill make a tutorial on http://p-xr.com when i get my eee pad tablet in a few weeks :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried again today - I get no errors and yet it does not work. I'll keep my eyes open for the tutorial.

Comment: Check the first line of the post: http://p-xr.com/customizing-the-action-bar-in-honeycomb/

Comment: It still won't work, do I have to do anything in the activity Java files, or just set the theme in manifest?

Comment: Please disregard all previous, looking at that .rar full of the source in eclipse and switching between the two files really made the difference, I had a few errors in my code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

For the first question, I think you can do like below:

1. In the onCreate() method, before the setConentView() add: 
   `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);`

   The Android system will automatically set background fill the whole screen.
2. create a transparent sharp "mysharp.xml"like below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape>
       <solid android:color="#55000000" />
   </shape>
   ```
3. set the action background

   ```
   getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mysharp));
   ```

Comment: For #3 you mean R.drawable.mysharp

Answer (score 5):

1. you can also declare action bar overlay in xml by

`<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`

just like here http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/res/values/styles.html

Answer (score 1):

In my Android 3 application I used

```
// Makes Action Bar Transparent
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
// END
```

and now the action bar is 100% transparent, Except for the stuff I add to it of course :)

Cheers